# Automate the Boring Stuff With Python Madlibs Project With Shelve Module

Tags: python-3.x

I've been learning python as my first coding language with the book 'Automate the Boring Stuff With Python', and after the chapter about reading/writing files and using the shelve module I managed to create the madlibs program. The only problem is I am sure I was suppose to use the shelve module, but I am still not sure how that works. Here is the code:

```
import re

basemadlibs = open('C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\MADLIBS.txt', 'r')
#creates a string out of the contents of the madlibs file
newmadlibslist = list(basemadlibs.read())
newtext = ''.join(newmadlibslist)
#regex for finding placeholders(VERB, ADJECTIVE, ect.) in the  madlibs file content
placeholders = re.compile(r'[A-Z]{2,10}')
#replaces the placeholders with a %s
emptytext = placeholders.sub('%s', newtext)
#creates a list of inputs to substitute the %s in the emptystring
replacements = []
for i in range(len(placeholders.findall(newtext))):
    print('type a\\an: ' + placeholders.findall(newtext)[i])
    replacement = input()
    replacements.append(replacement)
#string formats the %s placeholders with the replacements
madlibcompleted = emptytext % tuple(replacements)
#prints the completed mad lib
print(madlibcompleted)
#saves a copy of the completed madlib to the desktop called 'alterdMADLIBS.txt'
alteredmadlibs = open('C:\\users\\Username\\Desktop\\alteredMADLIBS.txt', 'w')
alteredmadlibs.write(madlibcompleted)
alteredmadlibs.close()
basemadlibs.close()
```

Can someone explain to me how the shelve module would make this more efficient? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> The only problem is I am sure I was suppose to use the shelve module, but I am still not sure how that works.

No, that's not mandatory. Though, it is mandatory for the previous problem. For this problem, you must use files, since you've also learned files in the same chapter.

Anyway, this is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

file = open('madlibs')
text = file.read()
file.close()

regex = re.compile(r'(ADJECTIVE)|(NOUN)|(VERB)')

for i in regex.findall(text):
    for j in i:
        if j != '':
            reg = re.compile(r'{}'.format(j))
            inp_text = input('Enter the substitute for %s: ' %j)
            text = reg.sub(inp_text, text, 1)

print(text)

file = open('madlibs_ans', 'w')
file.write(text)
file.close()
```

For me, this looks simpler. : )

Comment: Hey could you explain what this line of code basically does ?                                                          ```re.compile(r'{}'.format(j))``` . Thanks in advance

Comment: @kirtipurohit `.format()` just takes the argument and places it in the string (`{}`). [Try this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp)

Answer (score 3):

I did it without shelve, but still quite a bit more efficient than yours.

```
import re

#Open the Madlibs File
madLibs = open("..\\MadLibs.txt")
#Save the contents so you can modify it
content = madLibs.read()
madLibs.close()
check = re.compile(r'ADJECTIVE|NOUN|VERB|ADVERB')
#Loop to check for the words to replace
while True:
    result = check.search(content)
#end the Loop if there is nothing left to replace
    if result == None:
        break

#Get user input as soon as one is found (this if statement is just for
#grammatical correctness, and could probably be done better
    if result.group() == "ADJECTIVE" or result.group() == "ADVERB":
        print("Enter an %s:" % (result.group().lower()))
    elif result.group() == "NOUN" or result.group() == "VERB":
        print("Enter a %s:" % (result.group().lower()))
    i = input()
#substitute the word as soon as you come across it
#then Python only needs to search for one word at once, and automatically
#knows when it's done
    content = check.sub(i, content, 1)
print(content)
#Choose how to name the file you save and then save the file
print("Name your file:")
name = input()
newFile = open("..\\%s.txt" % (name), "w")
newFile.write(content)
```

The nice thing with coding is that there are multiple correct ways to do things. I am sure it would work with shelve, but you don't need it (and it might actually overcomplicate things).

Answer (score 1):

A shelf module is inappropriate for this, both the original madlib and the filled-in madlib are going to be a normal string of plaintext, .txt files work perfectly fine and allow the user to more easily edit and read the madlib files without digging into your code. However I do see a very inefficient two lines of code here.

Replace:

```
newmadlibslist = list(basemadlibs.read())
newtext = ''.join(newmadlibslist)
```

With:

```
newtext = basemadlibs.read()
```

basemadlibs.read() already returns a string, there's no reason to extract a list out of it

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution. I also did not use shelve.

Note: The `re.findall` was a really helpful way to parse out the parts of speech. It can identify parts of speech that have punctuation next to them. e.g `ADJECTIVE,` or `NOUN!` or `—ADVERB`.

Note: In my solution, all parts of speech in the `madlibsoriginal.txt` file must be uppercase.

```
import os, re

#Get original madlib text from the file
ORIG_FILE_MADLIB = open('/Users/mac/python/madlibs/madlibsoriginal.txt', 'r')
ORIG_MADLIB = ORIG_FILE_MADLIB.read()
ORIG_FILE_MADLIB.close()

#Parse the original madlib text into a list
split_madlib = re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;]|\s", ORIG_MADLIB)

#Declare list of parts of speech to (later) search for and replace
PARTS_OF_SPEECH = ['ADJECTIVE', 'NOUN', 'ADVERB', 'VERB']

#Search for parts of speech
for i in range(len(split_madlib)): #Tip: "For each word in the text"
    for j in range(len(PARTS_OF_SPEECH)): #Tip: "For each part of speech"
        if split_madlib[i] == PARTS_OF_SPEECH[j]: #Tip: "If the word is a part of speech"
            #Prompt for a replacement word
            new_word = input('Enter a ' + PARTS_OF_SPEECH[j].lower() + ': ')
            split_madlib[i] = new_word

#Create file with the new madlib text
NEW_FILE_MADLIB = open('/Users/mac/python/madlibs/madlibsnew.txt', 'w')
NEW_FILE_MADLIB.write(''.join(split_madlib))
NEW_FILE_MADLIB.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

So here's my solution. I started reading this book some weeks ago... Any tips will be appreciated.

```
#! /Users/santiagofacchini/.pyenv/shims/python

import re

path = '/Users/santiagofacchini/Desktop/text.txt'
input_file = open(path, 'r')
file_string = input_file.read()

file_string = re.sub(r'ADJECTIVE', input('Enter an adjective:\n'), file_string)
file_string = re.sub(r'NOUN', input('Enter a noun:\n'), file_string)
file_string = re.sub(r'ADVERB', input('Enter an adverb:\n'), file_string)
file_string = re.sub(r'VERB', input('Enter a verb:\n'), file_string)

output_file = open('/Users/santiagofacchini/Desktop/text_output.txt', 'w')
output_file.write(file_string)
print(file_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with..

```
import re

# Open Adlib File and new Adlib file
adlib = open('.\\adlib.txt')
new_adlib = open('.\\new_adlib.txt', 'a+')
content = str(adlib.readlines())


# Find capital word in file and prompt user to enter one
replace = re.compile(r'[A-Z][A-Z]+')
mo = replace.findall(content)
for i in range(len(mo)):
    new_word = input(f'Please enter a(n) {mo[i]}: \n')
    content = replace.sub(new_word, content, 1)
print(content)
new_adlib.write(content)

adlib.close()
new_adlib.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#! python3
import re
import pyinputplus as pyip

def quest(x):
    t = re.compile(r'(adjective|noun|adverb|verb)?', re.I)
    p = t.findall(x)                                         #<-Pick out all the 'adjective|noun|adverb|verb' 

    for k in list(p): 
        if k.lower() == 'adjective':
           print('Enter an adjective: ')
           adj = pyip.inputStr(blockRegexes =[r'adjective']) #<-Blocks the user from typing the word 'adjective' as a reply.
           a = re.compile(r'(adjective)', re.I)              #<-This regex will be used to substitute all matched phrases.
           x = a.sub(f'{adj}',x,1)                           #<-Replacing the matched phrases with user's input, using 'a.sub()'.
        elif k.lower() == 'noun':
           print('Enter a noun: ')
           nou = pyip.inputStr(blockRegexes =[r'noun'])
           a = re.compile(r'(noun)', re.I)
           x = a.sub(f'{nou}',x,1)
        elif k.lower() == 'adverb':
           print('Enter an adverb: ')
           adv = pyip.inputStr(blockRegexes =[r'adverb'])
           a = re.compile(r'(adverb)', re.I)
           x = a.sub(f'{adv}',x,1)
        elif k.lower() == 'verb':
           print('Enter a verb: ')
           ver = pyip.inputStr(blockRegexes =[r'verb'])
           a = re.compile(r'(verb)', re.I)
           x = a.sub(f'{ver}',x,1)

    print(x)

s = input('Enter a sentence: ')                             #<-The input text could be from anywhere, e.g. reading from a file, etc.

quest(s)
```

Comment: I hope this helps. You can now simply get the input sentence from either reading a file / shelve, copying from clipboard or just ask the user.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

# Open text file and save string to variable.
file_name = input("Enter the full name of the text file: ")
text_file = open(file_name, "r")
text = text_file.read()
text_file.close
# Create regex to find ADJECTIVE, NOUN, ADVERB, or VERB.
mad_libs_regex = re.compile(r"(ADJECTIVE|NOUN|ADVERB|VERB)")
# For each match, prompt user for word and update string.
while mad_libs_regex.search(text) != None:
    word = input(f"Enter a(n) {mad_libs_regex.search(text).group().lower()}: ")
    text = mad_libs_regex.sub(word, text, 1)
# Save updated string to new text file.
mad_libs_file = open(f"{file_name.split('.')[0]}_madlibs.txt", "w")
mad_libs_file.write(text)
mad_libs_file.close
# Print updated string.
print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't use the Shelve module but I just wanted to share my own slightly different solution using other things I've learnt from the book so far.

```py
#! python3

#   Usage: python3 madlibsScript.py inputTextFile.txt

import os, re, sys

# change current working directory to directory of input file.
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[1]))

# open text file and save content to python variable
inputTextFile = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
textFileContent = inputTextFile.read()
inputTextFile.close()

# regex object for placeholders
wordCheck = re.compile(r'VERB|NOUN|ADJECTIVE|ADVERB')

# check content for placeholders and get input from user for substitution
while wordCheck.search(textFileContent).group() in textFileContent:
    userInput = input('Enter your {}:   '.format(wordCheck.search(textFileContent).group().lower()))

    # substitute placeholder for the user input.
    textFileContent = wordCheck.sub(userInput, textFileContent, 1)

    # break from loop if there are no more placeholders
    if wordCheck.search(textFileContent) == None:
        break

# print to screen and save to file
print(textFileContent)

outputTextFile = open('madlibs-output.txt', 'w')
outputTextFile.write(textFileContent)
outputTextFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

For the example game with just 2 sentences, shelve will lengthen the code too much.
**But Shelve module could be used to scale up the game to the maximum extent in real-time projects.**

The code below takes the keywords e.g. Adjective, noun, etc.. and saves the data separately.
Then requests the user input and replaces every keyword in the game content.

### Code using Shelve

```
import re, shelve

def madlib(datapath, filepath):
    newShelf=shelve.open(datapath)
    userkeys=[]  
    newShelf["keywords"]=userkeys
    while True:
        userinput = input("Enter madlib rule keyword: ")
        if userinput=="":
            break
        else:
            userkeys.append(userinput)
            print("Press return key to save and exit.")
    newShelf["keywords"]=userkeys
    print(newShelf["keywords"])
    newShelf.close()
    
    madlib_file=open(filepath)
    game_content=madlib_file.read()
    madlib_file.close()
    print("\n\nGame content:\n"+game_content)
    
    datafile=shelve.open(datapath)
    match_data="|".join(datafile["keywords"])
    while True:
        mRegex=re.compile(match_data, re.I)
        match=mRegex.search(game_content)
        if match==None:
            break
        else:
            if match.group().startswith(("A","a")):  #for other vowels need to specify
                newWord=input(f"Enter an {match.group().lower()}: ")
            else:
                newWord=input(f"Enter a {match.group().lower()}: ")            
            game_content=mRegex.sub(newWord,game_content, count=1)
    datafile.close()
    print("\nOutput:\n"+game_content)
    file2=open(filepath,"w")
    file2.write(game_content)
    file2.close()
    
madlib("madlibData","madlibgamecontent.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

In the previous exercise we used the shelve module because we need a dictionary like file but here we don't (we have no key just a plain text.) So there is no reason to use it.Your code I think is correct, although very long. Here I am sharing my version (I chose not to store it at the end in a file)

```
import re
file_sentence = open('madLib.txt','r')
type_regex = re.compile(r'(ADJECTIVE|NOUN|ADVERB|VERB)',re.IGNORECASE)

for line in file_sentence.readlines():
    while type_regex.search(line):
        toChange = type_regex.search(line)
        ans = input('Please input a/an '+toChange.group())
        line = type_regex.sub(ans,line,1)
    print(line)
#then u can create a file and write on it.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
madlibFile = open('W:\\User\\textfiles\\madLib.txt')
text = madlibFile.read()
madlibFile.close()
check = re.compile(r'ADJECTIVE|NOUN|VERB|ADVERB')

while True:
    result = check.search(text)
    if result == None:
        break
    elif result.group() == "ADJECTIVE" or result.group() == "ADVERB":
        print("Enter an %s" % (result.group().lower()))
    elif result.group() == "NOUN" or result.group() == "VERB":
        print("Enter a %s" % (result.group().lower()))
    i = input()
    text = check.sub(i,text,1)

print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

so far I solved it like that
import re

```
fileName = input('what file to modify: ')
with open(fileName, 'r') as file:
    fileContent = file.read()

adjective = input('AJECTIVE = ')
noun = input('NOUN = ')
verb = input('VERB = ')

fileContent = fileContent.replace('ADJECTIVE', adjective)
fileContent = fileContent.replace('NOUN', noun)
fileContent = fileContent.replace('VERB', verb)

with open(fileName, 'w') as file:
    file.write(fileContent)
```

Answer (score 0):

My version is simpler and can be read easily. For vimlovers.

```
1 import re                                                                                                                  |  /home/kali/                  
2                                                                                                                            |  ▸   books/                  
3 file = open('sample.txt')                                                                                                  |  ▸   Desktop/                
4 content = file.readlines()                                                                                                 |  ▸   Documents/              
5 content = ' '.join(content)                                                                                                |  ▸   Downloads/              
6 word_regex = re.compile(r'(ADJECTIVE|VERB|NOUN)',re.IGNORECASE)                                                            |  ▸   Music/                  
7                                                                                                                            |  ▸   Pictures/               
8 print(content)                                                                                                             |  ▸   programming/            
9  words = word_regex.findall(content)                                                                                        |  ▸   Public/                                                                                                                                             |  ▸   Templates/              
11 print(words)                                                                                                               |  ▸   Videos/                 
12 for i in words:                                                                                                            |~                              
13                                                                                                                            |~                              
14 content = word_regex.sub(input(f"Enter an {i}?"),content,1)                                                            |~                              
15 file.close()                                                                                                               |~                              
16 file2 = open('output.txt','w')                                                                                             |~                              
17 file2.write(content)                                                                                                       |~                              
18 file2.close()                                                                                                              |~
```

~

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. I think it's pretty easy to understand. It also correctly puts a\an before the word.

```
import re

file = open('textFile.txt')
fileContent = file.read()
file.close()

wordRegex = re.compile(r'ADJECTIVE|NOUN|ADVERB|VERB', re.I)

print(f'{fileContent}\n')
for i in wordRegex.findall(fileContent):
    if i == 'ADJECTIVE' or i == 'ADVERB':
        userInput = input(f'Enter an {i.lower()}:\n')
        fileContent = wordRegex.sub(userInput, fileContent, 1)
    elif i == 'NOUN' or i == 'VERB':
        userInput = input(f'Enter a {i.lower()}:\n')
        fileContent = wordRegex.sub(userInput, fileContent, 1)

file = open('updatedFile.txt', 'w')
file.write(fileContent)
file.close()
```

Comment: Users find it difficult to understand code only answers with no explanation. Please consider adding some description explaining how it solves the problem.